# How to take multiple integers with spaces as input?

Tags: python, input, integer

I have to take 3 integer inputs separated by a space, eg. 3 4 5 and subtract each subsequent one from the next. E.g  3 from 4 and 4 from 5 and then add the results.

Does anyone know how I would go about doing this, here's the question I've been asked if you're interested:

The Lineland is a great infinite country, situated along the Ox axis. There are three cities in the Lineland. City A has coordinate xA, city B has coordinate xB and city C has coordinate xC.

A traveller Chloe lives in city A. She want to go first to city B and then to city C strictly in this order. But to prepare to the trip she needs to now the distance she will have to travel in advance.

Given the coordinates xA, xB, xC, find the distance Chloe will have to travel to get from city A to city B and then from city B to city C.

Input
The first line contains three space-separated integer numbers: xA, xB, xC (1 ≤ xA, xB, xC ≤ 100) — the coordinates of cities A, B and C.

Output
Print one integer number — the distance Chloe will have to travel to get from city A to city B and then from city B to city C.

Answer (score 1):

Your inputs will in string form, and you can split a string using `str.split(sep)`

```
def distance(start,end):
    # I'll leave implementation of this to you
    # use the distance formula if you want to impress your teacher
    # but since Lineland lies entirely upon one axis, this shouldn't
    # be very hard for you :)

# if in_ is your input
xA, xB, xC = in_.split(" ")
# you could also do = map(int,in_.split(" ")) to avoid the int() calls below
# but frankly I think using the map function is a lesson better suited for
# later.
chloes_travel_time = distance(int(xA),int(xB)) + distance(int(xB),int(xC))

print(chloes_travel_time)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer but I'm not sure how to implement checking if it's an integer, that and the fact the numbers are random so I have to use raw_input, any ideas?

Comment: @MitchellDoesntCare Not really sure what you're asking. You check if it's an integer by calling `int` on it and if it's not an integer, it will throw a `ValueError`. Whether you use `raw_input` (for Python2) or `input` (for Python3) shouldn't matter